# Formatting elements inside a loop in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below code. If the value of data.Day comes out like 7 Days can i format the variable before displaying it to show just the number.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in master">
 <td>{{ data.Day }}</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you want it to look like?

Comment: in the td instead of displaying 7 days it should just display 7

Comment: How is your data acquired? You may want to process the data in your controller or service and add an updated array to the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<td ng-bind="getDay(master.Day)"></td>
```

**In your controller**

```
$scope.getDay = function (data) {
    if (data && !isNaN(data.substring(0, data.indexOf(" ")))) {
        return data.substring(0, data.indexOf(" "));
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ajqcuw3s/1/)

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to deal with more than one digits.

Comment: Awesome..Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Updated the code to deal with more than one digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filters for that, but you will need write your own filter. But the better way is prepare you data before displaying it.